# Autofac multiple implementation of same interface and implements are called in a if logic

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, autofac

I have an interface called ibaseinterface using which I have created 2 classes lets say baseclass1 and baseclass2.

Now I have a class named as top-level as below

```
public class toplevel
{
    public ibaseinterface selection(string selection)
    {
        int.TryParse(selection, out int sel);
        if (sel < 2)
            return new baseclass1();
        else
            return new baseclass2();
    }
}
```

based on user input I select the class that needs to be called. so how do I resolve the dependencies, in this case, using autofac.

> Note: I definitely can't have different interfaces for the base classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you need to select an implementation based on some runtime data, the three typical solutions are:

- The Proxy design pattern
- The Adapter design pattern
- The Factory design pattern.

Here's an example of the factory design pattern:

```cs
public interface IBaseInterfaceFactory
{
    ibaseinterface selection(string selection);
}

public class toplevel
{
    private readonly IBaseInterfaceFactory factory;
    public toplovel(IBaseInterfaceFactory factory) => this.factory = factory;

    public ibaseinterface selection(string selection)
    {
        return this.factory.selection(selection);
    }
}

// This class depends on Autofac and should therefore be placed near your Autofac
// registations.
internal class AutofacBaseInterfaceFactory : IBaseInterfaceFactory
{
    private readonly IComponentContext context;
    public AutofacBaseInterfaceFactory(IComponentContext context) =>
        this.context = context;

    public ibaseinterface selection(string selection)
    {
        int.TryParse(selection, out int sel);
        if (sel < 2)
            return this.context.Resolve<baseclass1>();
        else
            return this.context.Resolve<baseclass2>();
    }
}
```

This can be wired up using the following code:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<toplevel>().AsSelf();
builder.RegisterType<AutofacBaseInterfaceFactory>().As<IBaseInterfaceFactory>();
builder.RegisterType<baseclass1>().AsSelf();
builder.RegisterType<baseclass2>().AsSelf();
```

Note that in the case that `toplevel`'s job is to just return a `IBaseInterfaceFactory`, in that cae `toplevel` already acts as the factory, and in that case it can be completely reduced from the equation.